Does Salesforce Pro Suite allows you to do apex?
I have been looking for this answer, but can't find it. Do you guys know if  you can create apex classes or triggers in salesforce Pro-Suite?.

The answer is probably "No, you can't create apex classes/triggers"
tl;dr: Salesforce continues to make a mess of their offerings. You may want to reach out to the Salesforce Sales Team to get a definitive answer, but that answer is almost certainly "no".
Salesforce has certainly made it more difficult than it needs to be to get at what features are actually included. The best I could find is this pdf listing the difference between features in the small business CRM starter suite and the pro suite.
Pro Suite gets you the ability to create custom objects, custom apps, use flows, use approval processes, have a sandbox, and install things from AppExchange.
Apex isn't explicitly mentioned, so I assume it's not included in the small business CRM product at all.
Looking at this only somewhat out-of-date official help article, The ability to create Apex classes (and triggers) is restricted to Enterprise and Unlimited Editions (and the Developer Edition, but that's not meant for general business use).
The current edition hierarchy appears to be (from least featured to most featured)
Essentials -> Starter (Suite) -> Pro (Suite)/Professional -> Enterprise -> Unlimited -> Einstein 1
Based on what I've seen now, I think that the Apex/Triggers feature may have been bundled under the banner of "Lightning Platform"

Meaning Professional is the cheapest product to use apex?

You will get following error message if you try to deploy apex code from VsCode: Deploy Errors: Not available for deploy for this organization
